# SAS macro import od many variables

Tags: import, sas-macro

I have table of three variables like trend, age and height. I know how to import trend variable using macro statement but I dont know how to import other variables? Age and height have values corresponding to five elements of seriesset (that's why I use qscan and scan functions). I want to add age and height for each value trends.

```
data aaa;
  input  listtrends age height;
datalines;
"low" 23 2
"negative" 23 4
"high" 22 3
"positive" 25 5
;
schools="polish_low_positive" "french_high_positive" "no_information" "spanish_negative";
run;
%let seriesset="low*negative*high*positive"; 

data bbb;
set aaaa;
    if
    %let i=1;
    %do %until (%qscan(&seriesset,&i,'*') = %str());
        %let trend=%scan(&seriesset,&i,'*');                    
          find("schools", "&trend")>2
        %let i =%eval(&i +1);
    %end;
    class=”&vschool”;
run;
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.  A concrete example will probable help clarify what you are asking about.

Comment: Hi @Tom, I edited my question.

Comment: Please show example values of the macro variables and the resulting SAS code that you want to generate for those values.

Comment: trend age height
low 23 2
medium 23 4
heigh 22 3
positive 24 3
negative 25 5
I want add for all cases in which schools variable contains two examples of macro variables "trend" (find function) appropriate values of age and height. To @Tom

Comment: @Tom I add SAS code for datasets

Comment: You are not defining the macro variables you are referencing.  Which is the set of data to be searched.  Is that the AAA dataset?  What is that you are searching for?